# Tomcat GUI access broken?

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, webapps, tomcat

I'm able to reach tomcat in the browser. I've done all the prep to be able to access the GUI apps, but I am still told I am not authorized.

I have my `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` in code blocks below. I'm using Tomcat 8.5.14 for Ubuntu 16.04 Linux.

in `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml`  --->

```
<tomcat-users> 
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat-admin" password="Newvegas3" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I've also suitably allowed connections to manager and host manager apps via this method from someone's post on a similar question.

In `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml`:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

In `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/host-manager.xml`:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager">
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

Now on the tomcat portal in browser I get prompted for password when trying to access the manager app or the host manager app but inputing the information from `tomcat-users.xml` and hitting "OK" just loops me to putting in my information without doing anything. When I escape the password prompt, I just get sent to an "error 401 unathorized page" for both manager app and host-manager app.

What gives? I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong even after hours of testing.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you restarted tomcat ? All your changes looks good.
However, read my post, where this contained detailed explanation

[how-to-access-tomcat-admin-manager-console-from-another-remote-machine](https://in.techiehints.com/wps/2017/08/09/how-to-access-tomcat-admin-manager-console-from-another-remote-machine/)

Comment: Ok Updated profile thanks for bringing me notice

Comment: Content that is linked to can disappear. Please add the relevant details here.

Comment: Ok I chnaged name since it was my old account, and also added my site preference in my profile and settings can you please review. Let me know what else I can add my details, I am glad to participate stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for guidance, I am actively using this site now. I will follow the same